# MySQL: Find "last modified" date from two tables

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have two MySQL tables:  **tech_requests** and **comments**.  I want to display each tech_request one time in a list ordered by the "last modified" date, whether that be the date of the tech_request creation or the latest comment tied to that tech_request.  I was trying to use UNION but I got stuck.  Any ideas would be much appreciated.  Here are the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `tech_requests` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `staff_member_id` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `date_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `request` text NOT NULL,
  `building_id` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `technician_id` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `completed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `subject` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `category_id` int(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=203 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `comments` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tech_request_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `technician_id` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `date_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `comment` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=234 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: If a tech request can have many comments then you can't just order a tech request based on the `date_time` of THE comment because it can have many comments :)

Comment: Noted, sorry for the poor etiquette

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
SELECT r.id, r.staff_member_id, ...,
       GREATEST(r.date_time, COALESCE(c.date_time, 0)) last_modified
  FROM tech_requests r LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT tech_request_id, MAX(date_time) date_time
    FROM comments c
   GROUP BY tech_request_id
) c
    ON r.id = c.tech_request_id
 ORDER BY last_modified
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/99537/2)** demo

Comment: Love the SQLFiddle demo too, never seen that before